# Issue with AssetBundles, and reading serialized values at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

I have a set of Asset Bundles that I load prefabs from. I don't simulate Asset Bundles in the editor, and when the Asset Bundles are downloaded from the website in the editor, the scripts and serialzed values work as expected.

However, when I actually make a WebGL build that uses those same Asset Bundles (also built for WebGL) and upload it, the prefabs all appear correct, but the info attached to them using Serializable fields of a MonoBehavior are all set to their default values. Am I missing some sort of flag for my Asset Bundle building or something?

The first time I ran into this issue (for my menu system) I went ahead and serialized the data to JSON to load later, but for this situation I don't view that as a viable solution.
The prefabs are models of metal parts, and said metal parts all have a specific ID (which is an int) which I use to represent the part.

I have cleared my cache in my test browser (firefox) and I am running in a private tab to prevent any data being saved between test sessions. I am sure that the asset bundles are being re-acquired properly as it takes about 4 eternities to download them on the internet I am on here.

```
public class PartInfo : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField]
    public float Length;
    [SerializeField]
    public string Sku;
    [SerializeField]
    public int Id;

    void OnValidate()
    {
        if (Sku == "")
        {
            Sku = gameObject.name.ToLower();
        }
    }
}
```

and

```
public void AddItem(GameObject go)
{
    PartInfo goInfo = go.GetComponent<PartInfo>();
    Debug.Log($"Found info attatched to part! {goInfo} with values {goInfo.Sku}, {goInfo.Id}, and {goInfo.Length}!!");
}
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention, this is the editor script I use to build the Asset Bundles:

```
    [MenuItem("Assets/Create Asset Bundles")]
    static void ExportBundle()
    {
        BuildPipeline.BuildAssetBundles(Application.dataPath + @"/../AssetBundles", BuildAssetBundleOptions.None, BuildTarget.WebGL);
    }
```

I expect the same output I get in the editor:

> Found info attatched to part! SHILT5(Clone) (PartInfo) with values shilt5, 406, and 7!!

To show in the Web GL build:

> Found info attatched to part!  with values , 0, and 0!!
>   (Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 48)

EDIT: I went ahead and updated Unity today, but it didn't help anything. I'm doing a non-stripped dev/debug build to see if I can figure anything out.

Comment: not a solution but in general note that `public` fields are by default serialized anyway so the `[SerializeField]` is a bit redundand here. It only makes sense if you want to serialize `private` fields

Comment: Made a note about this on forums, forget to show here, though.